# Converting dates in MySQL

Tags: mysql, date

I have a column in a MySQL database that has dates in the form:

`Tue Oct 25 2016`. I am trying to get it in the form `10/25/2016`.

I did some research and tried this:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(Date, '%d/%m/%Y') FROM table;
```

But it is returning null

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is type of your date column?

Comment: "What is type of your date column?" @MaximFedorov i assume when i see a format `Tue Oct 25 2016` it's one of the string types `varchar` or `char`

Comment: The datatype of the date column is text. Should I change it to something else? Thanks for the help. I was given this dataset so I didn't want to change anything until I had to. Looks like I might have to now

Comment: "The datatype of the date column is text. Should I change it to something else?" Yes because TEXT is stored separated from the table data and requires one extra random disk I/O per record (meaning 4 - 6ms extra time on normal HDD disk) to fetch the TEXT column atleast that's the case with InnoDB engine.. Besides you should choose a MySQL datatype that best matches for data for dates this is the `DATE` datatype

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Firstly, you will need to convert your date **string** to [MySQL date](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html) format (`'YYYY-MM-DD'`), using [STR_TO_DATE](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_str_to_date.asp) function. To convert from string, we have to specify the current format of the date string. In your case, it is `'%a %b %d %Y'`. Note that the `%` character is required before format specifier characters.

**Details:**

- `%a`     Abbreviated weekday name (Sun to Sat)
- `%b`     Abbreviated month name (Jan to Dec)
- `%d`     Day of the month as a numeric value (01 to 31)
- `%Y`     Year as a numeric, 4-digit value

Now, you can utilize [DATE_FORMAT](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_date_format.asp) function to convert the MySQL date into the desired date string format. In your case, it will be: '%m/%d/%Y'

**Details:**

- `%d`     Day of the month as a numeric value (01 to 31)
- `%m`     Month name as a numeric value (00 to 12)
- `%Y`     Year as a numeric, 4-digit value

Try the following query:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(Date, '%a %b %d %Y'), '%m/%d/%Y') 
FROM table;
```

Complete list of available format specifiers can be seen at: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format