# How to get Time from Mysql Date Format DD/MM/YYYY?

Tags: mysql, date, datetime

I want to get time from mysql `dd/mm/YYYY H:M:S` format.

I have tried,

```
SUBSTRING_INDEX(field, 'delimiter', index)
```

but am looking for a better solution.

have tried, `DATE_FORMAT(field, "%H:%i:%s")` but it returns `NULL` because my date format was not native `(YYYY-mm-dd)`

it was `02/05/2019 19:38:27`

How to get time from this above format in a better way?

**NOTE: I am storing date like above.. this fetching form SQL Server**

Comment: Stop storing dates as strings.

Comment: @SalmanA no i dont. .this actually from SQL Server.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting dates in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52369007/converting-dates-in-mysql)

Comment: Use `Str_to_date(...)` to convert the string to MySQL datetime, and then use `Date_format()` function to extract time out of it; or you can use the [`Time()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time) function. Use the above-mentioned question's answer as reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you can first use `STR_TO_DATE` followed by `CAST(... AS time)`. Casting instead of formatting allows you to use the result in date/time calculations.

```
SELECT CAST(STR_TO_DATE('02/05/2019 19:38:27', "%d/%m/%Y %H:%i:%s") AS TIME)
```

Ideally you should teach SQL Server to export dates in `yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss` format.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Salman A.  this is what i have tried, `TIME(STR_TO_DATE(d.in_punch, "%d/%m/%Y %H:%i:%s"))`

Answer (score 0):

This is how i Resolved,

```
TIME(STR_TO_DATE(d.in_punch, "%d/%m/%Y %H:%i:%s"))
```

also as per @Salman A

```
CAST(STR_TO_DATE('02/05/2019 19:38:27', "%d/%m/%Y %H:%i:%s") AS TIME)
```

this also worked.